# How to parse variable depth arrays into a struct from JSON

Tags: go

I am parsing JSON from an API into a struct. My code representing the struct is not working, and I have noticed that it is because the API is returning variable depth arrays (e.g. sometimes []float64, sometimes [][]float64). I do not know how to design a struct to handle this.

I have tried messing with my struct definition by swapping out the offending type between []float64, [][]float64, and []interface{}.

My code for my struct definition:

```golang
...
Geometries []struct {
    Type        string    `json:"type"`
    Coordinates []float64 `json:"coordinates"`
} `json:"geometries"`
...
```

Below is a sample output from the API:

```
...
"geometries": [{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-81.7046006, 41.4955689]}, {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-81.7176885, 41.507513], [-81.7205424, 41.4857622], [-81.6915158, 41.4836231], [-81.6886557, 41.5053737], [-81.7176885, 41.507513]]]}]
...
```

I expect the JSON to parse into the struct. Instead, I see the following error with the code:
`json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field .coordinates of type float64`

Comment: I have figured that much out. I am trying to find out if there is a way to handle both the format of the "Points" key ([]float64) as well as the "Polygon" key ([][]float64).

Comment: I think you can't do it with a struct because, as you point out, you'd need two alternatives for `Coordinates` both `[]float64` and `[][]float64`. One solution would be to pre-process the API output and convert any `Coordinates` of type `[]float64` to `[][]float64` so that every `Coordinates` is the same type and then marshal that. Alternatively -- not done this -- could you define `Coordinates` as `interface{}` and then post-process these?

Answer (score 2):

Use [json.RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) to capture the value that varies by geometry type:

```
Geometries []struct {
    Type        string          `json:"type"`
    Coordinates json.RawMessage `json:"coordinates"`
} `json:"geometries"`
```

Unmarshal the coordinates to a value appropriate for each type:

```
for _, geo := range x.Geometries {
    switch geo.Type {
    case "Point":
        var coords []float64
        if err := json.Unmarshal(geo.Coordinates, &coords); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(coords)
    case "Polygon":
        var coords [][][]float64
        if err := json.Unmarshal(geo.Coordinates, &coords); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(coords)
    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZKaFtF055Hs).

Another option is to unmarshal to `interface{}` and use [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to dig through the value:

```
Geometries []struct {
    Type        string      `json:"type"`
    Coordinates interface{} `json:"coordinates"`
} `json:"geometries"`

...

for _, geo := range x.Geometries {
    fmt.Println(geo.Type)
    dump(geo.Coordinates, "")
}

...

func dump(v interface{}, indent string) {
    switch v := v.(type) {
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Println(indent, "[")
        for _, v := range v {
            dump(v, indent+"  ")
        }
        fmt.Println(indent, "]")
    default:
        fmt.Println(indent, v)
    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fOESzW4eyEw).